# Why does Spark groupBy.agg(min/max) of BigDecimal always return 0?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdecimal

I'm trying to group by one column of a DataFrame, and generate the `min` and `max` values of a BigDecimal column within each of the resulting groups.  The results always produce a very small (approximately 0) value.

(Similar `min/max` calls against a Double column produce the expected, non-zero values.)

As a simple example:

If I create the following DataFrame:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => f}

case class Foo(group: String, bd_value: BigDecimal, d_value: Double)

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  Foo("A", BigDecimal("1.0"), 1.0),
  Foo("B", BigDecimal("10.0"), 10.0),
  Foo("B", BigDecimal("1.0"), 1.0),
  Foo("C", BigDecimal("10.0"), 10.0),
  Foo("C", BigDecimal("10.0"), 10.0),
  Foo("C", BigDecimal("10.0"), 10.0)
))

val df = rdd.toDF()
```

Selecting `max` of either the Double or BigDecimal column returns the expected result:

```scala
df.select(f.max("d_value")).show()

// +------------+
// |max(d_value)|
// +------------+
// |        10.0|
// +------------+

df.select(f.max("bd_value")).show()

// +--------------------+
// |       max(bd_value)|
// +--------------------+
// |10.00000000000000...|
// +--------------------+
```

But if I group-by then aggregate, I get a reasonable result for the Double column, but near-zero values for the BigDecimal column:

```scala
df.groupBy("group").agg(f.max("d_value")).show()

// +-----+------------+
// |group|max(d_value)|
// +-----+------------+
// |    B|        10.0|
// |    C|        10.0|
// |    A|         1.0|
// +-----+------------+

df.groupBy("group").agg(f.max("bd_value")).show()

// +-----+-------------+
// |group|max(bd_value)|
// +-----+-------------+
// |    B|     1.00E-16|
// |    C|     1.00E-16|
// |    A|      1.0E-17|
// +-----+-------------+
```

Why does spark return a zero result for these `min/max` calls?

Comment: Trying some different test cases helps refine the question - the value returned by `f.max` appears to be the correct value times 10^-17.  For instance, changing the example so that the largest value in group `C` is `123456.0` leads to `1.234560E-12`  as the max.  So, we can narrow the question to "Why are the exponents being mangled in max after groupBy?"

Comment: Another interesting tidbit: If I create the RDD as a `Seq` of `Row`s and create the schema myself (using the same `Decimal(38, 18)` that appears in the schema creating the DF using the case class), I get correct behavior.  Making the DF from a Sequence of Tuples gives the same incorrect behavior.  So, now we can ask "What happens when we create a DataFrame from an RDD of Rows with an explicit schema that's different from using a case class or Seq, and why do the latter cases mangle the exponents in BigDecimals?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

There seems to be an inconsistency in how Spark treats the scale of `BigDecimals` that manifests in the particular case shown in the question.  The code behaves as though it is converting `BigDecimal`s to unscaled `Long`s using the scale of the `BigDecimal` object, but then converting back to `BigDecimal` using the scale of the schema.

This can be worked around by either

- explicitly setting the scale on all `BigDecimal` values to match the DataFrame's schema using `setScale`, or
- manually specifying a schema and creating the DF from an RDD[Row]

## Long Version

Here is what I think is happening on my machine with Spark 2.4.0.

In the `groupBy.max` case, Spark is going through [UnsafeRow](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2228ee51ce3550d7e6740a1833aae21ab8596764/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/UnsafeRow.java#L265) and converting the `BigDecimal` to an *unscaled* `Long` and storing it as a Byte array in `setDecimal` at [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2228ee51ce3550d7e6740a1833aae21ab8596764/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/UnsafeRow.java#L288) line (as verified with print statements).  Then, when it later calls [getDecimal](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2228ee51ce3550d7e6740a1833aae21ab8596764/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/UnsafeRow.java#L393), it converts the byte array back to a `BigDecimal` using the scale *specified in the schema*.

If the scale in the original value does not match the scale in the schema, this results in an incorrect value.  For example,

```
val foo = BigDecimal(123456)
foo.scale
0

val bytes = foo.underlying().unscaledValue().toByteArray()

// convert the bytes into BigDecimal using the original scale -- correct value
val sameValue = BigDecimal(new java.math.BigInteger(bytes), 0)
sameValue: scala.math.BigDecimal = 123456

// convert the bytes into BigDecimal using scale 18 -- wrong value
val smaller = BigDecimal(new java.math.BigInteger(bytes), 18)
smaller: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.23456E-13
```

If I just select the max of the `bd_value` column, Spark doesn't seem to go through `setDecimal`.  I haven't verified why, or where it goes instead.

But, this would explain the values observed in the question.  Using the same case class `Foo`:

```
// This BigDecimal has scale 0
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Foo("C", BigDecimal(123456), 123456.0)))

// And shows with scale 0 in the DF
rdd.toDF.show
+-----+--------+--------+
|group|bd_value| d_value|
+-----+--------+--------+
|    C|  123456|123456.0|
+-----+--------+--------+

// But the schema has scale 18
rdd.toDF.printSchema
root
 |-- group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bd_value: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- d_value: double (nullable = false)


// groupBy + max corrupts in the same way as converting to bytes via unscaled, then to BigDecimal with scale 18
rdd.groupBy("group").max("bd_value").show
+-----+-------------+
|group|max(bd_value)|
+-----+-------------+
|    C|  1.23456E-13|
+-----+-------------+

// This BigDecimal is forced to have the same scale as the inferred schema
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Foo("C",BigDecimal(123456).setScale(18), 123456.0)))

// verified the scale is 18 in the DF
+-----+--------------------+--------+
|group|            bd_value| d_value|
+-----+--------------------+--------+
|    C|123456.0000000000...|123456.0|
+-----+--------------------+--------+


// And it works as expected
rdd1.groupBy("group").max("bd_value").show

+-----+--------------------+
|group|       max(bd_value)|
+-----+--------------------+
|    C|123456.0000000000...|
+-----+--------------------+
```

This would also explain why, as observed in the comment, it works fine when converted from an RDD[Row] with an explicit schema.

```
val rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("C", BigDecimal(123456), 123456.0)))

// schema has BigDecimal scale 18
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("group", StringType, true), StructField("bd_value", DecimalType(38,18), true), StructField("d_value",DoubleType,false)))

// createDataFrame interprets the value into the schema's scale
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema)

df.show

+-----+--------------------+--------+
|group|            bd_value| d_value|
+-----+--------------------+--------+
|    C|123456.0000000000...|123456.0|
+-----+--------------------+--------+
```